# Pandas multiindex dataframe merging

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, merge

Pandas multiindex merging question..
How to perform the operation below?

I have two dataframes:

```
1)

region                          Wenu              Wmunu            
process                    val_1   val_2       val_1  val_2
category    met     

2)

region                         Wenu                Wmunu            
process                       val_3                val_3
category    met  

merge to -->

region                         Wenu                 Wmunu            
process                  val_1  val_2 val_3    val_1  val_2 val_3
category    met
```